# jquery.mobile: how to ask user for date ranges?

Tags: jquery-mobile, daterangepicker

I need to ask users of my jquery mobile web site to select a date range.
I can't find any suitable jquery-mobile plugin. I looked for a lot of plugins for date-time picking (the most promising to me being "jQM-DateBox"), but no one seems to allow for a date range.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know there isn't any plugin which provides date ranges until now.

The available date plugins for jQM are

1. The [jQM-Datebox](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/)
2. The [MobiScroll](http://mobiscroll.com/)

In my opinion the most common way is to use two dateboxes, one for the start date and one for the end date. Initially the end date will be deactivated. The user will select the start date and using the change event you will have to complete the end date with the same date as the selected start date. Afterwards the user will have the option to modify the end date or not.

Comment: This can be a good idea... When displaying the end-date datebox, I could hide the start-date one, putting the second one in the same position... But I should be able to show user the start-date selection she did, with some css... do you think it's supported, or someway feasible? I should also be able to mark some dates as unavailable (grayed-out and disabled), if possible...

Comment: As you can see in the example code (dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/demos/opt/limit.html - Date Range input section), you can catch the change event and update the end date with the selected start date's value. Moreover you can use the range limiting options (http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/demos/opt/limit.html - Range limiting section) like blackDates or afterToday. Finally the Blacklisted dates section shows how to blacklist dates.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to use many arrays of blackDates? I want to give the user the information about availability, too, while she is selecting the date range...

Comment: Sorry, I did just read the docs, I only need one array of blackDates... :-)

Comment: The specific attribute is: "blackDates": ["2011-12-24", "2011-12-25"] so you can out in the array all the dates you want. You don't have to inform the end user since the unavailable dates will have grey (inactive) color :)

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure how it works in jQuery Mobile but you could try jQuery UI DateRangePicker (much of jQuery ui is in jQuery Mobile) ...

http://tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/

Ill be interested to know the outcome.